# A question on the real projective space.

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $\pi: S^n \to \mathbb{R} \textbf{P}^n$ be a map from the $n$-sphere to the real projective space of dimension $n$ given by $\pi(x)= \{ rx : r \in \mathbb{R} \}$. Is it true that for $n \geq 1$ it does not exist a continuous map $f: \mathbb{R} \textbf{P}^n \to S^n$ such that $\pi \circ f$ is the identity on $\mathbb{R} \textbf{P}^n$? In other words $\pi$ is not a retraction for $n \geq 1$?

Comment: @DisplayName not sure about the final conclusion, you are welcome to post an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I am sorry what I said was not true.

Answer (score 3):

If there were such a map (at least for $n > 0$), then from the sequence of maps
$$
\Bbb RP^n \xrightarrow{f} S^n \xrightarrow{\pi} \Bbb RP^n
$$
we get induced maps on $\pi_1$ or $H_1$ (with either $\Bbb Z$ or $\Bbb Z / 2\Bbb Z$ coefficients)

$$
H_1(\Bbb RP^n) \xrightarrow{f_{*}} H_1(S^n)  \xrightarrow{\pi_{*}} H_1(\Bbb RP^n)
$$
i.e., 
$$
\Bbb Z / 2\Bbb Z \xrightarrow{f_{*}} 0 \xrightarrow{\pi_{*}}\Bbb Z / 2\Bbb Z
$$
where the composite map $\pi_* f_*$ is the identity map on $\Bbb Z / 2\Bbb Z$ because it's a map induced by the identity homeomorphism on $\Bbb RP^n$. That's impossible, because the identity homomorphism on $\Bbb Z / 2\Bbb Z$ doesn't factor through the zero group.

(Exactly the same argument applies if you replace $H_1$ with $\pi_1$.)